# SSIS column when viewed in Dataflow is DT_NTEXT and column in table is NTEXT - When run in 32 Bit mode populates fine - does not work in 64 bit mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, type-conversion

I have an SSIS package that pulls in data from Oracle using an OLEDB connection. One of the columns in the table is a Long type which when pulled into the SSIS shows up as DT_TEXT. I use a data conversion to DT_NTEXT and map to a SQL Server table with data type as NTEXT.
This runs fine when run in 32bit Mode but in the 64 bit runtime it just populates the first character. Any ideas how to fix this weird issue?

Comment: On the Advanced Editor properties for the output column, what does the datatype and length say?

Comment: The advanced editor for the OLEDB Source says text stream(DT_TEXT) Code page 1252 and length obviously 0. The input column on the destination's Advanced Editor says DT_NTEXT

Comment: FWIW I've personally given up on this whole 64-bit thing due to endless obscure issues of a similar nature which are such a waste of time. Nowadays I tend to just force everything to run in 32-bit mode (where we are forced to develop and debug) if there are any non-SQL drivers involved (including Microsofts own drivers e.g. ACE), and just cop the hit on performance. MSFT have really made a mess of this IMO ... I'm so over it.